# Is it possible to delete deregister revisions from a CodeDeploy application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I noticed that the AWS CodeDeploy CLI does not have an option for deregistering revisions.

Is there any way to do this beyond deleting the application and re-creating it in CodeDeploy?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no "*de*register-application-revision" command in CodeDeploy so the workaround of deleting the Application to get rid of revision from CodeDeploy system may be the only way. Also, note that deleting CodeDeploy application will not remove the application revision from EC2 instances or S3 buckets.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/applications-delete.html